# Shrink VDI disk

Tags: hard-drive, virtualbox, partitioning, disk-space

I have vdi file for a disk of 40GB. The vdi file itself is 36GB. I made some room in the disk and was able to resize the partition of the disk to 20GB, leaving an unpartitionned space of 20GB.

I tried:

```
VBoxManage.exe modifyhd thedisk.vdi --resize 20480
```

which gives an error, and:

```
VBoxManage.exe modifyhd thedisk.vdi --compact
```

which leaves a vdi file of... 36GB.

How can I reclaim the unused space?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possibility is to fill the empty space from within the VM.

On Windows (`sdelete` is a [Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062) tool, and `X:` is the letter of the drive):

```
sdelete -z X:
```

On Linux:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/zero
rm /tmp/zero
```

(The `dd` command may run faster if you say `dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/zero bs=1M`.)

And **then** use the command (from the host):

```
VBoxManage.exe modifyhd thedisk.vdi --compact
```